# Paper Trail saving virtual attribute changes within object_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I am trying to persist virtual attribute changes within `object_changes` and have been working with the `meta` option.

```
has_paper_trail(
  meta: {
    status_name: proc { |foo| foo.status&.name }
  }
)
```

I added `status_name` to the `versions` table as the [docs](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata) mention, and that attribute does get persisted. However, instead of being saved within the `object_changes` hash, it is in its separate column, and the value does not include the previous value.

```
# version attributes:
object_changes:
  "{\"updated_at\":[\"2023-01-18T22:50:22.394Z\",\"2023-01-18T22:50:22.408Z\"],\"status_id\":[1,2]}",
 status_name: "Status 2"
```

This is working as the gem intends, but I'd like to push the `status_name` changes into `object_changes` and include the previous value. One way I've been able to get the before and after changes stored is by creating a new method using the `meta` flag. But it seems clunky, and I'm wondering if anyone has an alternative:

```
has_paper_trail(
    meta: {
      status_name: :track_status_name_changes
    }
  )

  def track_status_name_changes
    if versions.blank?
      [nil, status&.name].to_json # "[null,\"Status 1\"]"
    else
      prev_name = JSON.parse(versions.last.status_name).last
      [prev_name, status&.name].to_json # "[\"Status 1\",\"Status 2\"]"
    end
  end
```

I'm currently exploring creating my own adapter like mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#6c-custom-object-changes):

```
PaperTrail.config.object_changes_adapter = MyObjectChangesAdapter.new

class MyObjectChangesAdapter
  # @param changes Hash
  # @return Hash
  def diff(changes)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Going with the custom method in the meta flag I am able to track the changes of the virtual attribute, however, I'd also like to have those changes stored in the `object_changes` column of the versions table.